# Question on general analysis of Number and Perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many two-digit positive integers N have the property that the sum of N and the number obtained by reversing the order of the digits of N is a perfect square?
Answer given is 8.

Comment: Hint:  if $a,b$ are the digits then your sum is $11(a+b)$.

Answer (score 2):

As @lulu pointed it out, the sum of number and its reverse would be of the form $ 11*(a+b) $. 
For this to be a perfect square, (a+b) must be of the form $ 11*c $, where *c* is also a perfect square.

On solving it under the given constraints, we find that c must be 1.

So, a+b must be 11, we have

Thus, all the 8 possible two digit numbers are :
29,
38,
47,
56,
65,
74, 
83 and
92.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=10x+y$
Let reverse of $N=N'=10y+x$
$$N+N'=11x+11y=11(x+y)$$
So, $x+y$ must be $11$ to make $N+N'$ a perfect square.
Thus, there can be 8 possible two digit numbers $N$: $29,92, 38, 83, 47, 74, 56, 65$.